# Why dynamically created element won't fade out?

Tags: jquery, fade

I have dynamically created an element and want it to fadeOut after 2 seconds delay in an Ajax `success` callback.

```
success: function(response){
    if(response == "success")
        $("#main").prepend("<div class='success'>...</div>");
    else
        $("#main").prepend("<div class='error'>"+response+"</div>");

    window.setTimeout(
        function(){
            $(".success, .error").fadeOut()
        }, 2000);
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Is the new element being created and prepended successfully? i.e. is it just the fadeOut that is failing?

Comment: @RobCowie: Is it is being created successfully. The `.fadeOut()` fails. Just to mention I even tried Scratchpad (Firefox) to check if fadeOut() would work that way but it didn't.

Comment: Could you make a fiddle (if it works again)? It may be related to other parts of the code/html.

Comment: @dystroy: My full JS code: http://jsfiddle.net/ErkSn/

Comment: Try adding curly braces to the if...else. Perhaps the window.setTimeout() is considered part of the 'else' block and not running if response == 'success'. Long shot.

Comment: seems to work just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/bYpz8/

Comment: Ditch the `setTimeout()` and use `.delay()`. http://jsfiddle.net/x2HUy/

Comment: I see no reason why that wouldn't work (as Andy's fiddle shows), but if it was my code I would do it like this: `$("<div class='success'>...</div>").prependTo("#main").delay(2000).fadeOut();` (and similar for the error case).

Comment: Well, i am just trying in IE but it doesn't seem to perform even the ajax request. Can there be a better alternative to this? : `$(this).parents("form").attr('action')` which basically gets the parent form of the button clicked.

Comment: If it doesn't perform the ajax request then your elements won't even get created, so why are you asking about why `.fadeOut()` doesn't work? **Is the real question "Why doesn't my Ajax work?"**

Comment: @nnnnnn: But the Ajax works in Firefox (Courtsey: Firebug)

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not clear what else might be happening before or after your Ajax methods, you could try this approach:

```
success: function(response){
    var resultDiv = $('<div />', { text: response });
    if(response == "success")
        resultDiv.addClass('success').prependTo('#main');
    else
        resultDiv.addClass('error').prependTo('#main');

    setTimeout(function(){resultDiv.fadeOut()}, 2000);
}
```

I put together a crude JSFiddle that seems to prove this works: http://jsfiddle.net/LA7xN/. I've obviously not used an actual Ajax call, opting instead to just pass in a value to simulate the response.

Comment: Looks like the fadeOut is only called _after_ the new element is created, in the success callback. It ought to work.

Comment: @Phil, there is no event handler in the questioner's code, so how can your advice help him in this particular case?

Comment: Added a code sample that might attack the problem from a different angle.

Comment: Also: I would love to know why I'm being butchered in the votes when I think I've provided a reasonable answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your talk of event listeners doesn't seem to relate to the question at all, nor have you used event listeners in _your_ code, so...